# Multiply kernel and function

Tags: gpflow

Given a valid kernel k_1(x, x'), and a (parametric) function f(x), it follows that:

```
k_2(x, x') = f(x) k_1(x, x') f(x'),
```

is also a valid kernel.

Could you please tell me how to implement this property in gpflow?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve this in GPflow is to create a new class, that inherits from `Kernel`, which adds your desired functionality. The code you'll need for this will look similar to:

```py
import gpflow
from typing import Callable

class MyKernel(gpflow.Kernel):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, base_kernel: gpflow.Kernel, function: Callable):
        super().__init__(input_dim)
        self.base_kernel = base_kernel
        self.function = function

    def K(self, X, X2=None):
        if X2 is None:
            X2 = X
        return self.function(X) * self.base_kernel.K(X, X2) * self.function(X2)

    def Kdiag(self, X):
        return self.function(X)**2 * self.base_kernel.Kdiag(X, X2)
```

If you also want to optimise the parameters of `self.function` you will want to make sure that `self.function` inherits from the gpflow's `Parameterized` class. This will make sure that all its parameters are collected when the objective gets optimised.

Hope this helps you out.